# How to prevent user from removing "Custom Made" Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-registry, google-chrome-extensions

I want the extension which i created to be unremovable from chrome for monitoring it. I have tried creating registry values, but it only works with extension from webstore. When i create registry value for custom made extension, it is removing the extension and saying, "it is blocked by administrator"

#### What I have tried

1. Opened Windows Registry Editor
2. Opened the path the path Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\
3. Created new Key `Google/Chrome/ExtensionInstallForcelist`
4. Created a string value with name 1
5. Modified the value with `dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx` (Tampermonkey extension)
6. Relaunched Chrome

And it works fine..

When Do the same for `unpacked` extension, it gives he error
[image]

Comment: You'll probably have to read through Google's guide of "Managing Extensions in Your Enterprise" https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9296680?hl=en

Comment: I notice a possible typo in your URL which might be your problem. H:\Wat**hc**Dog should probably be H:\Wat**ch**Dog?

Comment: @LPChip no, i was lazy to rename in when i created the folder!